# Dealing with static functions when building a program as a library

Tags: c, unit-testing, static-libraries, static-functions

To implement unit testing for one of my programs, I've added a makefile rule to build the program as a static library when "make check" is run. I wrap main() with **#ifndef TEST_LIB** and **#endif** (**TEST_LIB** is defined when it's built as a library).

Then I created some small C files to test some functions from that library.

Some of the functions from the library are declared statically.

Which you may guess produces warnings such as this when I try to compile the tests:

> /../test/config_test.c:15:3: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘realize_home’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]

Because **realize_home** is declared statically in the source code (a .c file) for the program.

One solution I tried was to #include config_rmw.c (which contains the static functions) into the .c unit file (config_test). That actually works and doesn't give me any warnings when I compile, even though config_rmw.c is already built into the library.

Another solution I thought of was something like

```
#ifndef TEST_LIB
static
#endif
void function()
{
    definition
}
```

And adding the prototype to the header, which an #ifdef statement.

```
#ifdef TEST_LIB
function prototype
#endif
```

But doing that doesn't feel quite right, especially when it would have to be done for more functions as I proceed with implementing more unit tests.

I read in a book recently that static functions should go into a header file. I tried that but it only partially solved my problem. I wound up with compiler warnings like:

> In file included from ../../src/rmw.c:38:0:
>   ../../src/config_rmw.h:86:1: warning: ‘realize_home’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
>    realize_home (char **str)
>    ^~~~~~~~~~~~

I did some reading and I kind of understand why that happens. And basically that means I'd get a separate copy of that function in each .c file that #includes the header file where it's defined. Which I don't need. The reason I declare some functions statically is because they're only needed in one file.

Then I read some comments where people said static functions should never be defined in header files!

So... I'm stuck with wondering about the best approach and other options. I prefer to keep my programs organized and practice good coding skills.

I wrote some tests using just a script-based approach, which doesn't require my program to be built as a library, but I think there would be advantages to using both methods, depending on the functions that are being tested.

**UPDATE (Addition)** The program has 20 source files (including headers) and ~4K lines of code.

Comment: C doesn't really support unit testing (e.g. it is non-trivial to test static functions), but you can disable this warning with `-Wno-unused-function`.

Comment: The tests work but I was just hoping to implement it more "cleanly"; Right now I'm using the method where I #include the .c file containing the static functions into the test.c file. The results summary of the tests when using "make check" can be seen [at this link](https://travis-ci.org/theimpossibleastronaut/rmw/jobs/467882285#L798)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll do what was suggested [here](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/dealing-with-static-functions-when-building-a-program-as-a-library-4175644358/#post5938264)

I think #including the .c file will be fine for the tests. If for some reason that ever causes trouble, the "wrapper function" approach suggested by pan64 should be an acceptable compromise.

```
static void realize_home(char **)
{
    implementation
}
#ifdef UNITTEST
void test_realize_home(char **v)
{
    realize_home(v);
}
#endif
```